Book Similar to A Quiet Place
I rember a few scattered plot points.

Pretty sure the main character is an adolescent girl.
Her neighbour has a house with soundproofing that he made because he had a band.
Her house has an electric fence
The creatures are basically the same as from the movie
Later in the book there are soldiers with high tech body armor suits that stop bullets


In roughly which year did you read this?

Huh. More books than I thought on this theme: https://novelflavor.com/all/type/books-about-monsters+that+hunt+by+sound

Possibly Tim Lebbon's The Silence


In the darkness of a vast cave system, cut off from the world for millennia, blind creatures hunt by sound. Then there is light, there are voices, and they feed... Swarming from their prison, they multiply and thrive. To scream, even to whisper, is to summon death.
Deaf for many years, Ally knows how to live in silence. Now, it is her family's only chance of survival. To leave their home, to shun others, to find a remote haven where they can sit out the plague. But will it ever end? And what kind of world will be left?

Not matching, now that I've got access to a copy, is that I can't find any reference of a neighbor with a soundproofed room due to his band.

Why would a deaf person be any good at being silent? I guess sign language and lipreading would help, but not any more than a pen.

@Valorum My Ex's family all carry recessives for congenital deafness, she can hear but her cousins can't, only people I've ever met who can sneak up on me without trying. Taht's not the only time I've noticed the difference, I don't know why but deaf people tend to just be quieter, they breath quieter, they don't even rustle as much when they're moving around, large groups are disconcertingly silent and not just because they're not talking.
